# Excel formula to be converted to Power BI M query

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a excel formula which will basically count database and weeks and tells me how many weeks each database is taking to load data.

```
IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, G:G, "<>"&G2)>0,"Two Weeks", "One Week")
columnB is my database column
columnG is my week column
```

Now I am trying to add a custom column in `PowerBI`, in that column I want to display One Week or Two Weeks for each row  of database.

Can some one help me with equivalent M query for this excel formula.

I tried the following

```
= if List.Count(Table.SelectRows(DBTimeline, each [DataBase] = [DataBase] and [Week Number] <> [Week Number])) > 0 then "Two Weeks" else "One Week"

= if List.Count(Table.SelectRows("Previous Step", each [DataBase] = [DataBase] and [Week Number] <> [Week Number])) > 0 then "Two Weeks" else "One Week"
```

DBTimeline is my table name in PowerBI

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step","Misc",(x)=>if List.Count(Table.SelectRows("Previous Step", each x[DataBase] = [DataBase] and x[Week Number] <> [Week Number])) > 0 then "Two Weeks" else "One Week")
```

Comment: tried the suggested formula but not working, creating a new column with error.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to this, I have added created a new column using DAX measure in visual and it is giving me the desired output.